# Change option menu button place in CustomTkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ribbon, customtkinter

I need to have a button like this:

[image: Button with a option menu that drop]

Something like a ribbon. I'm using CustomTkinter but all that I can do on normal TkInter I can do on CustomTkinter. I have a [CTkOptionMenu](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkOptionMenu), he do the thing that I want, but I want to change his button with the dropdown arrow for botton and place a image on main text, like the Ribbon button.

My question is, have a form to I create my own option menu widget or that I can put the dropdown button and the image on the OptionMenu of CustomTkinter or in Tkinter?

**EDIT:**

I find that have a widget named MenuButton, he seans like the widget that I need, but in the code say:

```
"""Menubutton widget, obsolete since Tk8.0."""
```

I can use and style he with no problems or have a better solution?

**Maybe be a answer:**

Ok, I readed the CustomTkinter source code, and I made [this code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W6EiUqumtOkHUn_REVkWoFEBtRi4T23U/view?usp=share_link) to create a button with the dropdown menu (CTkMenuButton). Its basically the same that the normal CTkButton, but with some variables and functions of CTkOptionMenu. I don't know if its have some issue, so I need that someone read to see if its a right answer.

Comment: The menubutton isn't obsolete, this seems to be something that only the tkinter author believes. There's no mention of it being obsolete in any of the official tk documentation.

Comment: Ok. So I only need a way to style the menuButton, to be uniform with the rest of custom TkInter application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand all of what you are asking, but this example would create a toolbar in tkinter using PIL

[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root: tk.Tk):
        super().__init__()
        self.root = root
        self.fileMenu: tk.Menu

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.root.title("Toolbar")

        toolbar = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED)
        img = Image.open("paste.png")
        tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        paste_button = tk.Button(toolbar, image=tk_img, relief=tk.FLAT, command=self._paste_clipboard)
        paste_button.image = tk_img
        paste_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=1, pady=1)

        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.pack()

    def _paste_clipboard(self):
        # insert code to paste data here
        print('paste clipboard')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200")
    main_window = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The OP wants a menu attached to the button. This answer doesn't do that.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley You're right, I want a menubutton. But thanks anyway, Ovski.